# Why do we need numeric literals in Java?

Tags: java

I have simple question, why do we need to use special literals when it's already obviously what type of variable we are using.

For example, you can see that we are using double type here. And I think compiler should also see it. But if I run such code:

```
double no_double = 60*(1000/3600);
System.out.format("result is: %.3f",no_double);
```

I get the result is: `0,000`.

But if I run that code:

```
double a_double = 60.0*(1000.0/3600.0);
System.out.format("result is: %.3f",a_double);
```

Then I get true result: `16,667`.

So why do we need to use literals ?

**up.** Java Primitive Data Types http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: These are all literals.  What you mean is, "why do we need to explicitly distinguish between integer and floating-point literals?".

Comment: But the answer is; because that's not how the language works.  In general, types of subexpressions are not inferred from where they're being used.

Comment: @Reimeus `double` is not a name at all, it is a keyword and naming a variable `double` will make the compiler fail :)

Answer (score 4):

You're dividing two integers.
The result of that is another integer.

Assigning that integer to a `double` value later doesn't change the division.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious, as the compiler (or JVM) cannot know if you really want floats or integers.

I'd argue that floating point math is hard, if you consider all the corner cases. Floats are inprecise by design, whereas with integers, you get exact results. If you can stick to exact results it is often better to do so and resort to floats only when explicitly needed. For example, if you need to compare the equality of two variables, with floats you have to give it some boundaries and definitions as to what you consider to be equal. With integers there is no need for this, it is self-evident.

There are sevaral programming languages where this kind of explicit separation does not happen, possibly javascript and PHP being the most popular. They choose to autoconvert the datatypes on the fly. It causes some considerable overhead and additional issues in the long run, when you need to know *exactly* what is this variable you have in your hands.

Still other programming languages exist that don't even have these different data types. Maybe everything there is just an object. This is one way of solving it.

Comment: "floats are imprecise" - not really; their behaviour is well-defined.  They just have different characteristics to integer types.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the behaviour is only well-defined if you use floats as specified by IEEE standard or some other rigid standard. This does not apply to all floats (but yes, it does apply for java floats). My main point was though that float internal representation typically means they're inprecise as values when you try to use them in base-10 number world, even if their behaviour is well-defined.

Comment: I think it's important to make that distinction, though.  `2.0/5.0 == 1.333333333333` is certainly no less precise than `2/5 == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just part of the specification of Java as a C-type language.  [Per the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17), if integer values aren't promoted in an expression, then the result of the calculation is an integer.   The language designers could have decided to make the result of all calculations floating point numbers, but decided not to, probably because that behavior for primitive types was not familiar to C and C++ programmers, and because it makes the operations slower.